# MsgBox if a cell value contains partial text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet set up whereby in column M a location is entered, however it needs to stop people using abbreviations - I'm trying to set up a MsgBox that appears if for example "J/W" is entered in a cell in range `M5:M1000` but can't seem to get it to work? I assume it would be a private sub as below?

EDIT: it needs to search for partial values so it would check the cells once the text has been entered completely.

```
Private Sub IncorrectText()

    If InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M5:M1000").Value, "J/W") > 0 Then

        MsgBox "Please DO NOT use abbreviations" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Change this to 'at/ from the junction with...'"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't get a value from a range in this way.  You can loop through the cells or use the Change event to only detect changed cells.

Comment: Or Use `Range.Find` for this purpose. but Better would be the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to capture the cell changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Worksheet.Change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) to check the input immediately after the cell was edited. Then use `Application.Undo` to undo if some not allowed things were entered.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M5:M1000"))  'check if change happened in the desired range

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange
            Select Case True
                Case InStr(1, Cell.Value, "J/W") > 0
                    MsgBox "do not use 'J/W'"
                    Application.Undo
                    Exit For

                Case InStr(1, Cell.Value, "c/o") > 0
                    MsgBox "do not use 'c/o'"
                    Application.Undo
                    Exit For
            End Select
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: If one of the forbidden abbreviations is inserted then undo.</sup>*

If you don't need individual message boxes you can use this instead. So you can just put all abbreviations into a list:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M5:M1000"))  'check if change happened in the desired range

    Dim NotAllowedList() As Variant
    NotAllowedList = Array("c/o", "J/W")

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim FoundNotAllowed As Boolean
        Dim Cell As Range, NotAllowed As Variant
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange
            For Each NotAllowed In NotAllowedList
                If InStr(1, Cell.Value, NotAllowed, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    FoundNotAllowed = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next NotAllowed

            If FoundNotAllowed Then Exit For
        Next Cell

        If FoundNotAllowed Then
            MsgBox "do not use abbreviations"
            Application.Undo
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thank you - is there a way to check so it doesn't match the case? ie can say "J/W" or "j/w"?

Comment: @ffc2004 yes use `InStr(1, Cell.Value, "J/W", vbTextCompare)` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @ffc2004 see my edit, if you don't need individual messages.

Comment: Apologies - another quick one, is there a way to include multiple strings in the same line? e.g. `Case InStr(1, Cell.Value, "KT1" OR "KT2", vbTextCompare) > 0`

Comment: That doesn't work. You need to connect the `InStr` with OR like `InStr(1, Cell.Value, "KT1", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, Cell.Value, "KT2", vbTextCompare) > 0` or list the cases comma separated like `Case InStr(1, Cell.Value, "KT1", vbTextCompare) > 0, InStr(1, Cell.Value, "KT2", vbTextCompare) > 0`

Comment: Fantastic, as well as searching the string for partial text, how could I search for exact text?

Comment: @ffc2004 `Case Cell.Value = "ExactText"`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without VBA through a custom Data Validation with a Formula like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("J/W";M5;1));True())
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to put your logic into a Worksheet Event.
In the VBE editor, double click the name of the sheet the user will enter the data. 
In the worksheet module that appears use the selection change event like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 

 If Not IsError(Application.Match("J/W", Range("M5:M1000"), 0)) Then msgbox("write your message here")

End Sub
```

Now if someone enter J/w ad press enter the MSGbox will pop up.